# Hiding a frame depend on textbox value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is the last stage of my Python file.
What I am attempting to do is have frame 5 unhidden when Textbox2 value is between 2 numeric numbers.
This an piece out of my original 100+ frames file.

I was able to complete this whole file as an Excel file.

I am stuck on the code for Deff onclick 5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks as always!!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("1000x900")
  

def onclick5():
   if ([textbox2], [">0" and "<10.1"]):
      frame5.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=2,sticky="NW")
   else:
      frame5.grid_forget()



def onclick1():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '2.83')

def onclick2():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
    textbox1.insert('end', '5.66')

def onclick3():
    textbox1.delete('1.0', 'end')
textbox1.insert('end', '8.49')

def to_float( string ):
    try: 
        return float( string )
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0

def onclick4():
    tot = 0.0
    for box in text_boxes_to_sum:
        v = box.get( '1.0', 'end' )
        tot += to_float( v )
    textbox2.delete( '1.0', 'end' )
    textbox2.insert( 'end', str(tot) )

  




button_var1 = tk.IntVar()
button_var2 = tk.IntVar()

frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame5 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")

textbox1 = Text(frame2, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=2)
textbox1.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w")
textbox2 = Text(frame3, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="NESW")
textbox3 = Text(frame5, borderwidth=1, wrap="none", width=10, height=1)
textbox3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NESW")
text_boxes_to_sum = [ textbox1 ]  


frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
label = Label(frame2, text="Select # Of Units Being Used", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady= 1, padx=1, sticky= "W")

frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
label = Label(frame3, text="Total CFM Values", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady= 1, padx=1, sticky= "W")

frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=0, bg="lightyellow")
frame4.grid(row=8, column=0, pady=2,padx=3, sticky="E")

frame5 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=0, bg="lightyellow")
label = Label(frame5, text="Reccommended Compressor Package", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady= 1, padx=1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame5, text="Compressor Package 1", fg="black")
label.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 10, padx=5, sticky= "EW")

button1=Radiobutton(frame2, text="1 Unit ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick1)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button2=Radiobutton(frame2, text="2 Units ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick2)
button2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button3=Radiobutton(frame2, text="3 Units ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick3)
button3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")
button4=Radiobutton(frame3, text="Show Values ", variable=button_var1, command=onclick4, value = 0 )
button4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")

button5=Radiobutton(frame4, text="Show Reccommended Compressor Package ", variable=button_var2, command=onclick5)
button5.grid(row=0, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have been been working on this for about 2 weeks

Below are some of the things I have tried.
No error are display but will not display frame 


def onclick5():
   if (textbox2 == "0><10.1"):
      frame5.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=2,sticky="NW")
   else:
      frame5.grid_forget()

def onclick5():
   if (textbox2 == ">0<10.1"):
      frame5.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=2,sticky="NW")
   else:
      frame5.grid_forget()

def onclick5():
   if (textbox2 == ">0" and "<10.1"):
      frame5.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=2,sticky="NW")
   else:
      frame5.grid_forget()

Comment: I  have added my latest attempt at my def 5 function. It will unhide the frame but the else function has no effect. I have tried numerous variation of the code with no positive results.